# Capitalizing a lower case screen name at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: capitalization, internet, sentence-starts

When starting a sentence with a lower case pseudonym, such as a screen name of a user account on a website, should it be capitalized? Or are there different cases where it would and would not be appropriate to do so?

My curiosity was sparked by [this meta EL&U page](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253/referencing-the-existence-of-words-that-may-be-offensive/265#265) where a user comments that he does not mind if his name is lower-cased or not.

Are there any established standards on this practice?

Comment: Though both answers below *merely suggest* avoidance, I would say that the *standard practice* is to avoid doing it.

Comment: Agree strongly with rewording the sentence being the best bet. Its important to note that some systems are case-sensitive, e.g., `Anthony` and `anthony` are two *different* user names. For those systems especially, never change the case.

Comment: You could compare it to product names like iPod, companies like eBay, and artists like e e cummings or k d lang; such names are often discussed in newspaper style guides, even if they don't consider screen names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing professionally, the first letter in the sentence is capitalized, sole exceptions being when the capitalization could result in a misunderstanding. In such cases, the word is usually typeset differently.

However, when writing in an informal context, you might want to take into consideration the preference of the user. For example, Randall Munroe prefers his username [xkcd to remain lowercase](http://xkcd.com/about); however, as you've linked, some users like nohat do not mind it being capitalized. If you are unsure, I would suggest capitalizing it and adhering to professional writing style.

Comment: Exception: technical contexts with case-sensitive terms. Usually it's best to reorder the sentence, but the typical solution is to set the terms in a fixed-width typeface. `this` is the sort of thing I mean.

Comment: @Jon When I was writing it, I was racking my brain trying to think of somewhere was case-sensitivity mattered, since I was pretty sure there was some case somewhere that I just couldn't think of. Thanks for finding it for me.

Comment: 'Q: How do I write "xkcd"? There's nothing in Strunk and White about this.

A: For those of us pedantic enough to want a rule, here it is: The preferred form is "xkcd", all lower-case. In formal contexts where a lowercase word shouldn't start a sentence, "XKCD" is an okay alternative. "Xkcd" is frowned upon.'

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid this issue by starting the sentence differently:

> The user `elufan123` is running for moderator ...

Comment: +1 -- but I prefer "The artist known as ..."

Comment: Although your answer gives a more direct response for the “best practices” of this situation, waiwai933 more directly answered my questions. If I could, I'd accept both of your answers, though!

Answer (score 1):

Where possible, I would suggest avoiding putting a username at the start of a sentence, otherwise to pick a style and follow it. Above all, write clearly and unambiguously.

> Are there any established standards on this practice?

I asked the editors of [the Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/) newspaper's [style guide](http://www.guardian.co.uk/styleguide) about this:

> [Q.](https://twitter.com/hugovk/status/92639481160679424) What's your style on capitalising (sometimes case-sensitive)
>   usernames? And how about at the start of a sentence? Or just avoid it?
>
> [A.](https://twitter.com/guardianstyle/status/92903293117927424) **We spell it however the user does, including at the start of a
>   sentence.**

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a problem.

H/horatio is right about the common practice:

> Though both answers below merely suggest avoidance, I would say that the standard practice is to avoid doing it.

I guess it gets down to the standard answer to orthography questions: choose some way to cope with it. If you're important enough, it may stick (think iMac etc.)